# How to copy the content of sub-dir without a custom Ant task?

Tags: jenkins, ant, jenkins-plugins, fileset

I'm working with Jenkins 2 and trying to copy artifacts between jobs and in turn to an S3 bucket.

I have a simple web build which produces artifacts in `/dist/public` which I'd like to upload into the S3 bucket.

So once the job completes, I have a folder /dist in the workspace root. Jenkins gives you the ability to copy artifacts between jobs which leverages Ant's `fileset`.

The issue I'm having is that this is a restricted subset of Ant and all you're provided is include & exclude paths.

I can use `dist/public/**/**` however this copies the parent directories across also.

What I would prefer is to only copy the content of `public/` but after doing some reading it seems this may be difficult to do without a custom Ant tasks, etc.

Answer (score 0):

If you copy files by Ant, you should set:

```
<fileset dir="/dist/public"/>
```

at you copy task, or you can use [`flatten` attribute](https://ant.apache.org/manual/Tasks/copy.html).

If you use Jenkins artefact collector (as I do), I think now you have to copy this files to workspace root (see: [Copy Artifact Plugin](https://wiki.jenkins-ci.org/display/JENKINS/Copy+Artifact+Plugin)).